# Development of a Drag and Drop Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, draggable, defaults

I'm starting to become a plugin creator and don't fully have the hang of it. One problem is I would like to make an default where you have two numbers. And I need to be able to apply them to the code.

What I mean is like this:

```
var defaults = {
numbers: [1, 2]
}
```

I like how the jquery team did it with draggable:

```
$('#drag').draggable({
grid: [1, 100]
});
```

Which is something I would like to do. Any Idea how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One nice way to do this is to use [`$.extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend), which merges the contents of two or more objects together into the first object:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.foobar = function(options) {
        var settings = {
            numbers: [1, 2]
        };
        $.extend(settings, options);

        /* continue with plugin code. */           

        alert(settings.numbers[0] + " " + settings.numbers[1]);
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Now `settings` is a combination of the user-specified options and the "default" options. See [this section](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Defaults_and_Options) of the plugin authoring tutorial for more information.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/2Djya/

**P.S:** A good resource for figuring out how plugins work is the [jQueryUI source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js#L183) itself.

Answer (score 0):

simplified plugin code:

```
$.fn.yourPlugin = function( conf ){
    var config = $.extend({
        someVar : 'default'
        ,   foo : 'anotherDefault'
    }, conf );

    return this.each( function(){
        // do stuff with $( this ) and config
    } );
};
```

the `$.extend` will copy any params from `conf` which is passed in onto the object you create that sets the defaults.